# Have an issue undefined index to my blade view in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have an issue undefined index to my blade view in laravel 5.6. I have to run my URL localhost:8000/test while am getting an error **Undefined index: Domains**.if pass some values in the url like localhost:8000/test?tld=test&sld=info it is working perfectly.please suggest any solution.

My View page Code

```
@foreach($result['Domains']['Domain'] as $key => $value)
      @if($key == 'Name')
      <b>{{$value}}</b> - 
      @endif
      @if($key == "RRPText")
      <b>{{$value}}</b>
      @endif
      @endforeach
      @foreach($result['Domains']['Domain']['Prices'] as $key => $value)
      @if($key == "Registration")
      <b>{{$value}}</b>
      @endif 
      @endforeach
```

My Controller Code

```
$sld = $request['sld'];
        $tld = $request['tld'];
        $response = file_get_contents('https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld='. $sld .'&tld='. $tld .'&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw&responsetype=xml&version=2&includeprice=1&includeproperties=1&includeeap=1');  
        $data = simplexml_load_string($response);
        $configdata   = json_encode($data);
        $final_data = json_decode($configdata,true);
```

My output of the API call

```
{"interface-response":
{"Domains":
{"Domain":
{"Name":"decksys.info","RRPCode":"210","RRPText":"Domain available","IsPremium":"False","IsPlatinum":"False","IsEAP":"False","Prices":{"Currency":"","Registration":"12.48","Renewal":"12.48","Restore":"250.00","Transfer":"12.48","ExpectedCustomerSuppliedPrice":null}}},"Command":"CHECK","APIType":"API.NET","Language":"eng","ErrCount":"0","ResponseCount":"0","MinPeriod":"1","MaxPeriod":"10","Server":"sjl0vwapi08","Site":"eNom","IsLockable":null,"IsRealTimeTLD":null,"TimeDifference":"+0.00","ExecTime":"0.553","Done":"true","TrackingKey":"a1c38f08-5042-4139-a525-302d987a2b39","RequestDateTime":"5/25/2018 4:23:31 AM","debug":null}}
```

Please suggest any solution

Comment: Whats the output of the API call?

Comment: my output is too long can you please run the below URL
[ http://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?UID=decksys&PW=Amy.th3ist4917&SLD=decksys&TLD=info&Command=check&responsetype=json&version=2&includeprice=1]

Comment: i am not permitted : User not permitted from this IP address, just post the first 2 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's says undefined index, that means key for `$result['Domains']['Domain']` or `$result['Domains']['Domain']['Prices']` doesn't exists in array.

try to dump your `$results` variable, using `dd($results)` before the foreach and you will find there isn't the key.

You can do check with `isset()` for check that index exists in that array

```
@if(isset($result['Domains']['Domain'])) 
    @foreach($result['Domains']['Domain'] as $key => $value)
      @if($key == 'Name')
        <b>{{$value}}</b> - 
      @endif
      @if($key == "RRPText")
        <b>{{$value}}</b>
      @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
@if(isset($result['Domains']['Domain']['Prices']))
    @foreach($result['Domains']['Domain']['Prices'] as $key => $value)
      @if($key == "Registration")
        <b>{{$value}}</b>
      @endif 
    @endforeach
@endif
```

You can learn more about PHP arrays here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp